# Empty Variable for UILabel in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I need to create a variable for a UILabel in Swift.  I want to initialize it in the viewDidLoad method but I need the variable to be globally accessible.  I have tried:

```
var locationLabel:UILabel
```

But Xcode wants me to initialize the label at that point which I don't want to do. How can I do this?

Comment: You can make it an optional with `?`

Comment: Hadn't thought of that approach.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.  I figured it out.  This worked:

```
var locationLabel = UILabel()
```

Comment: and if label expected to be initialised only once, use let locationLabel instead!